# Where have I used commutative (coproduct in $\mathbf{Ab}$ vs. $\mathbf{Grp}$)

Tags: category-theory, products, abelian-categories

There are different questions about the coproduct in **Ab**, the coproduct in **Grp** and why they are so differents. However, I wonder why the following constructions cannot be extend for arbitrary groups:

Given two abelian groups $(A,+),(B,+),$ the set $A\times B$ endowed with the natural law $(a,b)+(a',b')=(a+a',b+b')$ together with the natural inclusions $\iota_A:A\rightarrow A\times B$ and $\iota_B:B\rightarrow B$ is the coproduct (for $A$ and $B$).

I guess I am using commutativity at some point (maybe to prove it satisfies the required universal property) but I cannot find where. If this construction were valid for any group in **Grp** then products and coproducts would match in **Grp** (for finite families), which is false. So, where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243791/coproducts-in-textab?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The typical proof that your $A \times B$ satisfies the universal property of the coproduct in $\mathbf{Ab}$ is as follows:
if $f: A \to C$ and $g: B \to C$ are two homomorphisms of abelian groups, then there is the induced homomorphism $h: A \times B \to C$ defined by $h(a,b) = f(a) + g(b)$. In order for this to be a homomorphism, $C$ must be abelian, for
$$ h(a,b) + h(a',b') = f(a) + g(b)  + f(a') + g(b') $$
and
$$ h(a+a',b+b') = f(a) + f(a') + g(b) + g(b'),$$
so $f(a')$ and $g(b)$ must commute for all $a' \in A$, $b \in B$ in order for the desired homomorphism to actually be a homomorphism.

Comment: Ok. That is exactly what I was looking for. I'll accept the answer as soon as they allow me.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that you assume commutativity within $A$ and $B$, but rather that $i_A(A)$ and $i_B(B)$ commute.
For $A=B=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, we have homomorphism $f_A\colon A\to S_3$, $1+2\Bbb Z\mapsto (1\,2)$ and $f_B\colon B\to S_3$, $1+2\Bbb Z\mapsto (1\,3)$. However, there is no suitable $h\colon \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to S_3$ with $h\circ f_{A}=i_A$ and $h\circ f_B=i_B$.

Comment: What do you mean by $i_A(A)$ and $i_B(B)$ commutes? By the way, you mean $f_A=h\circ i_A$.